# Nationality on Academic CV in USA

Tags: cv

Is it acceptable to put your nationality on a CV when applying for a position at an American university?

For your interest, in some countries it is customary to put your date of birth, marital status, or even your religion on your CV. As far as I understand, this gets an application binned immediately in the USA. But what about nationality?

Comment: May I ask what you intend accomplish with that?

Comment: Probably putting the country of your passport and whatever relevant visas you have would be of minor interest, but, supposedly, hiring choices at many universities are not supposed to depend on visa/passport situations...

Comment: In some countries you put your date of birth, your gender, and even your religion on your CV. I am simply asking for the convention and legal implications.

Comment: At least prior to the upcoming administration (I'm soooo sorry, I apologize to everyone...) there were very few nationalities that would be excluded at all from consideration. An example: maybe Iranians currently excluded from nuclear physics/engineering programs. (I don't necessarily endorse this...) But I think that has been the only sort of exclusionary principle, if that's the concern. About the future... well, ... >:-(

Comment: _in some countries it is customary to put your [...] religion on your CV. As far as I understand, this gets an application binned immediately in the USA._ I'm pretty sure that's false. Certainly it would be morally questionable to disqualify an application on those grounds, and will likely be illegal as well. The correct thing to do is to simply ignore the irrelevant information (and certainly as an employer one is prohibited from asking about something like an applicant's religion, but the applicant him/herself is free to volunteer any information they wish to share, in the CV or elsewhere).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen it many times on applications, and it made not a shred of a difference. We did occasionally have Iranian applicants, which is probably the most problematic case, but again it made no difference -- if we wanted to hire someone because of their qualifications, we still did not care about visa issues because that's someone else's problem. For any other nationality, it was a non-issue that wasn't even talked about.

To show you what else doesn't matter: Because I'm German, I put my nationality, birthday, and marital status on my CV for all my postdoc and assistant prof applications. It made no difference: I got invitations to interviews and offers regardless. I don't do it any more because I've learned that that's not typically done in the US. But it really made no difference one way or the other, neither legally nor as far as the hiring committee is concerned.

In summary: You're overthinking the issue :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, don't include it.  Generally, for a US position, your nationality won't be directly relevant to the decision.

There are a few cases in which nationality might be indirectly relevant is if the institution wants to know if you already have authorization to work in the US, or if you would need a visa.  There may also be positions (especially postdocs) which are funded by the government and reserved for US citizens or permanent residents.  But if one of these is the case, they'll ask that question directly on the application, and you just have to answer yes or no.  Either way, the CV isn't the place to put that information.

Comment: This seems inaccurate. Aren't many postdocs funded by grants that can only support US citizens or permanent residents? (like e.g. NSF RTG grants)

Comment: Would it be harmful to include it if it's not required?

Comment: @dbluesk: For positions where it's not relevant, hiring committees will know they can't take it into consideration.  So if you list it, they will have to make an effort to disregard it and make sure it doesn't influence their decision.  That can be a distraction, and you don't want to cause them unnecessary distractions.